# Laravel routing/data issue

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

So I am using the same code for my controllers and for one of them isnt working. I have found it to be web.php/route:list.

If i use

```
Route::resource('/jaybills', 'Jay_BillsController');
```

I get this error when trying to access jaybills/{jay_bill}/edit

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\hayes\Desktop\laravel\resources\views\jaybills\edit.blade.php)
```

I have used dd() in the controller and for some odd reason me using this

```
public function edit(Jay_Bill $jay_bill)
{
  $jay_bill = Jay_Bill::find($jay_bill->id);
  return view('jaybills.edit', [
    'jay_bill' => $jay_bill
  ]);
}
```

returns null. I have used this in 3 other controllers and works fine. If i put manually the id, the code then works fine...

if I manually add the routes in web.php like this

```
Route::get('jaybills/{jay_bill}/edit', 'Jay_BillsController@edit');
Route::get('jaybills', 'Jay_BillsCOntroller@index');
```

the code then works as expected and returns my data i expect and not NULL...

I would love some ideas as i have spent hours debuging this and have come to this conclusion and have no idea why or how to fix it.

UPDATE - Added Controller and view and model.

CONTROLLER

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Jay_Bill;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Jay_BillsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $jay_bill = Jay_Bill::all();

        return view('jaybills.index', [
            'jay_Bill' => $jay_bill
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('jaybills.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $jay_bill = Jay_Bill::create([
            'jay_bill_name' => $request->input('jay_bill_name'),
            'jay_bill_account' => $request->input('jay_bill_account'),
            'jay_bill_cost' => $request->input('jay_bill_cost'),
            'jay_bill_due' => $request->input('jay_bill_due'),
            'jay_bill_paid' => $request->input('jay_bill_paid')
        ]);

        return redirect('bills/');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Jay_Bill  $jay_bill
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Jay_Bill $jay_bill)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Jay_Bill  $jay_bill
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Jay_Bill $jay_bill)
    {
        //
       dd(Jay_Bill::find($jay_bill->id));

        // return view('jaybills.edit', [
        //     'jay_bill' => $jay_bill
        // ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Jay_Bill  $jay_bill
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Jay_Bill $jay_bill)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Jay_Bill  $jay_bill
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Jay_Bill $jay_bill)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

MODEL

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Jay_Bill extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "jay_bills";
    protected $fillable = [
        'jay_bill_name',
        'jay_bill_account',
        'jay_bill_cost',
        'jay_bill_due',
        'jay_bill_paid'
    ]; 

    // Adds carbon to the view, so that its possible to use carbon's functions in blade view.
    public function getJayBillDueAttribute()   

    {

        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['jay_bill_due']); 

    }
}
```

VIEW

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<form method="post" action="jaybills/{{$jay_bill->id}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="jay_bill_name">Bill Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jay_bill_name" id="jay_bill_name" placeholder="Enter Bill Name" value="{{ $jay_bill->jay_bill_name }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="jay_bill_account">Bill Account</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jay_bill_account" id="jay_bill_account" placeholder="Enter Bill Account" value="{{ $jay_bill->jay_bill_account }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="jay_bill_cost">Bill Cost</label>
      <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" name="jay_bill_cost" id="jay_bill_cost" placeholder="Enter Bill Cost" value="{{ $jay_bill->jay_bill_cost }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="jay_bill_due">Bill Due</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="jay_bill_due" id="jay_bill_due" value="{{ $jay_bill->jay_bill_due->format('Y-m-d') }}">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
          @if($jay_bill->jay_bill_paid == 1)
          <input type="hidden" name="jay_bill_paid" value="0" unchecked/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="jay_bill_paid" value="1" checked> Paid
          @else
          <input type="hidden" name="jay_bill_paid" value="0" checked/>
          <input type="checkbox" name="jay_bill_paid" value="1" unchecked> Paid
          @endif
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
  </form>

@endsection
```

So if you are not sure what the issue is. Basically I have a button that goes to jaybills/{jayBill}/edit - jayBill is basically the id of the data.

I then get the error mentioned above however I have the same code in another controller/view/model and it works. I have found if i manually create the route it works and if I manually input the id into ::find(1); it also works fine.

Update #2

I have tried this

```
dd(JayBill::find($jayBill->id));
```

This returns NULL. I i manually put in 1 in the find function, everything works fine. I have tried dd() on my other controllers and it returns the data with the id. why cant it find the id from the code above? its not picking it up?

UPDATE #3

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Jay_Bill {#229 ▼
    #table: "jay_bills"
    #fillable: array:5 [▶]
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }
  1 => "1"
```

Comment: now what is the problem

Comment: added more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your route parameter is wrongly formatted, if you want to use implicit model binding you should call it `jay_bill` with an underscore, instead of `jayBill`.

Comment: Sorry as I'm fairly new to laravel. Are you talking the array in returned view? If so then would it be my key I change or the value?

Comment: I think he is talking about route binding https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: Thanks. I will look at that see what i can get from it. its just strange it doesnt work for this controller but does for others.

Comment: I have managed to solve it *somehow* but i believe everyone was on the right lines the naming convention was incorrect. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Route::resource('/jaybills', 'JayBillsController',[
   'parameters' => [
'jaybills' => 'jaybill'
]]);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but unfortunately that didnt help :(

Comment: put dd(func_get_args()); in one of methods in controller that have the model as argument and give me the result

Comment: Thanks for helping again. I have updated the main post.

Comment: in which method of controller did you put that?

Comment: edit method. I have even tried changing the naming conventions and still the same issue.

Comment: I have managed to solve it *somehow* but i believe everyone was on the right lines the naming convention was incorrect. Thanks everyone!

Comment: please send your config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in your controller `$jayBill` to `$jaybill`

The model binding don't recognize camel case

Comment: Thanks for helping but that didnt seem to fix it either.

Comment: I have managed to solve it *somehow* but i believe everyone was on the right lines the naming convention was incorrect. Thanks everyone!